# Using the '@' symbol for a display name in an email address

Tags: email, rfc

Good morning everybody,

Technically, I know I can use any ASCII character in the display name of an email.

Is there any reason to avoid the '@' character in the display name?

I am thinking to use something like: "John Doe @ Company Name", so the full email address would be something like that:

```
"John Doe @ Company Name" <john.doe@company.com>
```

- Is there any implication in the anti spam filtering process on any major ISP?
- Is there any risk that this email would be viewed as phishing?
- Is it a good practice?

I know the question maybe weird, but thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a test and try emailing a hotmail or gmail account with that as your display name and seeing if it was delivered with no problems. I don't see why it would be a problem to be honest

Comment: Thanks, I made a test with bout gmail and hotmail, and it seems to be fine so far.